# How to make expandable div to show first element and toggle rest

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, expand

I have few sections on my webpage with different type of news stories. Some with images, some without (just text). I want be able to display the first paragraph or first div of each story and then on click toggle the whole content of the div (story).

I've found this bit of code on CSS Tricks website:

```
var news = 2;

hidenews = "- Hide news archive";
shownews = "+ Show news archive";

$(".archive").html( shownews );
$(".news:not(:lt("+news+"))").hide();

$(".archive").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
       if ($(".news:eq("+news+")").is(":hidden")) {
           $(".news:hidden").show();
           $(".archive").html( hidenews );
       } else {
           $(".news:not(:lt("+news+"))").hide();
           $(".archive").html( shownews );
       }
});

<div class="news">First news</div>
<div class="news">Second news</div>
<div class="news">Third news</div>
<a class="archive" href="#"></a>
```

It works great, but only with one div. With multiple ones on the page when I click show button it opens all the divs.

Can anyone help me to edit the code so only one story opens on click not all of them, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is modified version of your code

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var news = 0;

    hidenews = "- Hide news archive";
    shownews = "+ Show news archive";

    $(".archive").html( shownews );
    $(".news").hide();
    $(".archive").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    var $container = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.accordion-container');
           if ($container.find(".news:eq("+news+")").is(":hidden")) {
               $container.find(".news:not(:lt("+news+"))").slideDown();
               $container.find(".archive").html( hidenews );
           } else {
               $container.find(".news:not(:lt("+news+"))").slideUp();
               $container.find(".archive").html( shownews );
           }
    });

    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="title">First news</div>
    <div class="news">Second news</div>
    <div class="news">Third news</div>


    <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="title">First news</div>
    <div class="news">Second news</div>
    <div class="news">Third news</div>


    <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="title">First news</div>
    <div class="news">Second news</div>
    <div class="news">Third news</div>


    <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="title">First news</div>
    <div class="news">Second news</div>
    <div class="news">Third news</div>


    <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="title">First news</div>
    <div class="news">Second news</div>
    <div class="news">Third news</div>


    <a class="archive" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks. Is it possible to have it collapsed on load? Right now when page loads the whole stories are shown.

Comment: Also how hard would be to add nice smooth transitions?

Comment: @user7040259 please check the answer is edited for transittions and default collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `toggle` button for each element.

```
//Hide all content
$('.content').hide();
$('.archive').click(function(){
  //Get content DIV
  var content = $(this).parent('.news').find('.content');
  //Content toggle
  content.toggle();
  //Show / Hide adjusted
  $(this).text(content.is(":visible") ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
});
```

```js
$('.content').hide();
$('.archive').click(function(){
  var content = $(this).parent('.news').find('.content');
  content.toggle();
  $(this).text(content.is(":visible") ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="news">First news
 <div class="content">First news Content</div>
  <a class="archive" href="#">Show</a>
</div>
<div class="news">Second news
  <div class="content">Second news Content</div>
  <a class="archive" href="#">Show</a>
</div>
<div class="news">Third news
  <div class="content">Third news Content</div>
  <a class="archive" href="#">Show</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bootstrap accordian. You may have to edit a bit.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion </h2>
 
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Accordion is not really what I'm after. I need the button below the story to be Read/View more and once the div is extended chang it to Read/View Less.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Accordion feature.Check this link
 https://jqueryui.com/accordion/